# Handling expired sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Alot of my controllers have functions that look like this. What is the best measure to take with CI when a session runs out and a function like such is called?

```
$this->foo_model->create_bar($this->session->userdata('userid'), $bookId);
```

Comment: *Alot of my controllers have functions...* immediately suggests that you are not following DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) paradigms. You should be able to have this logic in one spot. Consider Using Controller Inheritance so that the Mother Controller looks after session handling and your individual controllers don't have to. See [this post](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully get your question maybe, but when you call `$this->session->userdata('something')` for an expired session it will simply return `FALSE`.

So, the best method would be checking if the variable isn't FALSE? As you would do with any other variable that might not be the value you want:

```
if($this->session->userdata('userid')){}
//or check it into the model's method, wherever you prefer
```

Where and when to do that strongly depends on your design. If you always need to do the same check you might want to make it a library or a model's function, so that you just need to write your code once and just call that method. If you need it done before anything else you might consider placing it in the constructor, or as @Jordan Arsenault suggested, create a parent MY_Controller which does the check, and all your regular controllers extends it. Really, this depends on you architecture and you didn't provide enough info to answer that.

All I can say is make your methods fault tolerants, always check for the correct value before feeding the rest of your code (if an expired session breaks your workflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to revive an expired session.For example you can create a token for users when they login to your application .This token has a related userid that your application knows globally then save a cookie on the user machine that contains the token.each time the session expires ask for the client cookies and see if this cookie is available then with its userid re-create the session.if there's no token available redirect your user to a page telling him what has happened and ask him to login again.
When the user logs out delete the token and the cookie

Comment: Yeah, but if the cookie's not there the above code will probably produce an error, so I don't think this is a solution to the problem.

Comment: As I said if no cookie is available or cookies are not enabled at the client side you should redirect the user to a page telling him what happened and ask him to login again.

Comment: You are right, sorry. The reason I commented was that I thought persisting a session in cookies is related, but does not answer the question.

Comment: You are right .The DRY problem still remains and should be refactored so that reading the userid from the session won't be all over the place.But until then I think it's wise to have a mechanism to bring back the session to a valid state